# How to escape brackets in android studios?

Tags: java, android

I know this is kinda stupid, but i just recently switched from eclipse to android studios, and in eclipse you could press tab to escape brackets, instead of using your mouse or using arrow keys. Is there a way to do this in android studios?

Comment: The last time I pressed tab in Eclipse I'm pretty sure it inserted a tab character. So what is it that you are after?

Comment: In eclipse, if it automatically adds a second parentheses when i add the first(which it always does). Then, to get out of the new parentheses, i press tab, which takes my cursor to the right of the second parentheses. same thing with brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say that Android Studio simply does not do this yet.

On my Mac, the closest thing has been autocompleting things with <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>, which will bring up a list of possible commands you'd want to autocomplete, and when you hit enter, will help you fill in the variables and automatically place the parenthesis and all.

Comment: i was afraid of that

Comment: Is this still the same or has "escape brackets" feature been finally added to Android Studio?

Comment: @Green as far as I understand, it hasn't been added yet

Comment: @AlexK that is quite unfortunate. Thanks!